# Using DatagramPacket in Java

Tags: java, datagram

To send a String through a DatagramPacket we use:

```
 String msg = "example";
 byte[]data = msg.getBytes();
 DatagramPacket pktOut = new DatagramPacket(data, 0, data.length, dest, port)
```

How to send an array through a DatagramPacket ?

```
 int num[] = {50,20,45,82,25,63};
 //I need to send this over two packets, but I don't know how to deal
//with arrays when sending them
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what do you mean with this?
the problem is: I don't know how to start converting this array to a form which it can be sent over a packet.. code sample plz ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the Integer-array to a byte buffer using the [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class.

```
int num[] = { 50 , 20 , 45 , 82 , 25 , 63 };
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate( num.length * 4 );
for ( int i : num ) {
    bb.putInt( i );
}
byte[] data = bb.array();
```

Comment: why u used num.length * 4 ?

Comment: Because an integer has 4 bytes and the buffer should allocate enough space for all integers from num[] (6*4=24 bytes).